# C++ trouble filling vector (should be easy fix) need to save 1-9 as characters to vector. fill vector not working

Tags: c++, vector, char

need to save 1-9 as characters to vector. fillVector method does not seem to be working. The out put will display as boxes which I assume means null.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

bool xIsWinner(vector <char>&);
bool oIsWinner(vector <char>&);
bool draw(vector <char>&);
//void fillArray(char a[]); //comment out later, leave for now.
void fillVector(vector<char>&);
//void displayBoard(const char a[]);
void displayBoard(vector<char>& a);
void replaceWithXorO(vector <char>& a, int& b, char& c);
void checkForWinner(vector <char>&);
void checkForWinner(vector <char>&);
void readInXorO(vector<char>& , int& b, char& c);



int main()
{
    vector <char> a;
        char letterX = 'X';
        char letterO = 'O';
        int x = 0;
        int o = 0;
        //char cells[9] = {0};
        vector <char> cells;

    //fillArray(cells);
    //fillVector(cells);


    while(true)
    {
        displayBoard(cells);


        //checkForWinner(cells);
        if(xIsWinner(cells) || oIsWinner(cells) || draw(cells))
        {
                return 0;
        }

        readInXorO(cells, x, letterX);
        replaceWithXorO(cells, x, letterX);
        displayBoard(cells);
        checkForWinner(cells);

        if(xIsWinner(cells) || oIsWinner(cells) || draw(cells))
        {
            return 0;
        }

        readInXorO(cells, o, letterO);

        replaceWithXorO(cells,o,letterO);
    }
    return 0;
}

//bool xIsWinner(char a[])
bool xIsWinner(vector<char>& a)
{
for(int k = 0; k < 9; k = k + 3)
{
    if (a[k] == 'X' && a[k + 1] == 'X' && a[k + 2] == 'X')
    {
           return true;
    }
}
for(int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
{
    if (a[k] == 'X' && a[k + 3] == 'X' && a[k + 6] == 'X')
    {
           return true;
    }
}
if (a[0] == 'X' && a[4] == 'X' && a[8] == 'X')
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if (a[2] == 'X' && a[4] == 'X' && a[6] == 'X' )
    {
        return true;
    }

return false;
}

bool oIsWinner(vector <char>& a)
{
for(int k = 0; k < 9; k = k + 3)
{
    if (a[k] == 'O' && a[k + 1] == 'O' && a[k + 2] == 'O')
    {
           return true;
    }
}
for(int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
{
    if (a[k] == 'O' && a[k + 3] == 'O' && a[k + 6] == 'O')
    {
           return true;
    }
}
if (a[0] == 'O' && a[4] == 'O' && a[8] == 'O')
    {
     return true;
    }
    else if (a[2] == 'O' && a[4] == 'O' && a[6] == 'O' )
    {
     return true;
    }
return false;
}

//bool draw(char a[])
bool draw(vector <char>& a)
{
if (a[0] == 'X' && a[1] == 'O' && a[2] == 'X' && a[3] == 'O' && a[4] == 'X' && a[5] == 'X' && a[6] == 'O' && a[7] == 'X' && a[8] == 'O')
    {
    return true;
    }
    else if (a[0] == 'X' && a[1] == 'O' && a[2] == 'X' && a[3] == 'X' && a[4] == 'O' && a[5] == 'O' && a[6] == 'O' && a[7] == 'X' && a[8] == 'X')
    {
    return true;
    }
    else if (a[0] == 'X' && a[1] == 'X' && a[2] == 'O' && a[3] == 'X' && a[4] == 'O' && a[5] == 'X' && a[6] == 'O' && a[7] == 'X' && a[8] == 'O')
    {
     return true;
    }
    else if (a[0] == 'O' && a[1] == 'X' && a[2] == 'X' && a[3] == 'X' && a[4] == 'X' && a[5] == 'O' && a[6] == 'O' && a[7] == 'O' && a[8] == 'X')
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if (a[0] == 'X' && a[1] == 'O' && a[2] == 'X' && a[3] == 'O' && a[4] == 'X' && a[5] == 'X' && a[6] == 'X' && a[7] == 'X' && a[8] == 'O')
    {
        return true;
    }

return false;
}

/*void fillArray(char a[])
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        a[i] = i + 49;
    }
}*/
void fillVector(vector<char>& a){
    a.clear();
    for(int i=0; i<9; i++){
    char k= i;
    a.push_back(k);
    }
}

/*void displayBoard(const char a[])
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 9; j = j + 3)
    {
        cout << a[j] << " " << a[j + 1] << " " << a[j + 2] << endl;
    }
}*/

void displayBoard(vector<char>& a){
    for(int j=0; j<9; j++){
        cout<< a[j];
    }
}

void replaceWithXorO(vector<char>& a, int& b, char& c)
{
    a[b - 1] = c;
}

//void checkForWinner(char a[])
void checkForWinner(vector <char>& a)
{
    if(xIsWinner(a))
    {
        cout << "Winner is: X" << endl;
    }
    else if(oIsWinner(a))
    {
        cout << "Winner is: O" << endl;
    }
    else if(draw(a))
    {
        cout << "Draw!" << endl;
    }
}
void readInXorO(vector<char>& a, int& b, char& c)
{
    bool notNumber = false;
    char letterX = 'X';
    char letterO = 'O';

    do
    {
        cout << c << " position: ";
        cin >> b;

        notNumber = cin.fail();

        if(notNumber)
        {
        cin.clear(); // clears the error flags
        cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); // this line discards all the input waiting in the stream
        cout << "Illegal move!" << endl;
        }
        else if(b < 1 || b > 9)
        {
            cout << "Illegal move!" << endl;
        }
        else if(a[b-1] == letterX)
        {
            cout << "Illegal move!" << endl;
        }
        else if(a[b-1] == letterO)
        {
            cout << "Illegal move!" << endl;
        }
    }while(notNumber || b < 1 || b > 9 || (a[b-1] == letterX) || (a[b-1] == letterO));
}
```

breaking out the method I believe is not functional

```
            void fillVector(vector<char>& a){
            a.clear();
            for(int i=0; i<9; i++){
            char k= i;
            a.push_back(k);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (‘**why isn't this code working?**’) must include the desired behaviour, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: you need `char k= i+'1';
    a.push_back(k);`

Comment: Also, you have `fillVector(cells);` commented out.

Comment: good catch, but I am still getting [][][][][][][][]�X position:

Comment: Why you're using a vector for this and not just a fixed `std::array<char,9>` is somewhat of a mystery in itself. Regardless, filling with `'1'` through `'9'` becomes trivial via `std::iota(ar.begin(), ar.end(), '1')`, so long as there are nine spots already open in the container (i.e. no clear, and in fact assurance via resize).

Comment: I am not allowed to use arrays on this one.

Comment: Doesn't change the rest of what I said one iota (pun intended).

Comment: I got it mostly fixed but now my O wins is not printing. The program will stop like it knows it won, but will not print the win statement for just O
http://ideone.com/OjS2SA

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:
char k= '0' + i;

Comment: void fillVector(vector<char>& a){
 a.clear();
 for(int i=0; i<9; i++){
  char k= '0' + i;
  a.push_back(k);
 }
}

Comment: void fillVector(vector<char>& a){
     a.clear();
     for(int i=0; i<9; i++){
      char k= '0' + i;
      a.push_back(k);
     }
     }

Comment: nvm, it was already posted by  Jean-François Fabre. 
@Merle Ledbetter: just so u know, I just tried to run your code, it has multiple seg faults!

Answer (score -1):

If you want a[i] to be character of digit i, a[i] = '0' + i;

Comment: I tried that but I can't get the vector to initially print anything but [][][][][][][][] initially. However once I start putting in x's and 0's the []'s will be replaced. I am missing something here...